# Can't choose C++ language standard in Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, c++17

For some reason I cannot choose C++ language standard in Visual Studio. By saying that I mean next thing:
I can go to the properties and choose the language standard but Visual Studio doesnt see that. How did I came to that: I tried to include filesystem header with setting the C++17 standard set  but then I saw that filesystem is not a member of std namespace: [image: Is not an std member]

First, I thought that it was not an C++17 standard so I double checked that. After me checking all the stuff again I decided to go to the header file and check the stuff going wrong. I saw that _HAS_CXX17 is disabled although in properties C++17 is set: [image: _HAS_CXX17 is off]

I have no additional libraries connected in properties and this version of Visual studio has to be working with all of that C++17 headers because I had to work with them and still can compile these projects I've been working on, but I can't switch standard on any project now. No library were installed during period it were working last time. I updated Visual studio recently but it didnt help althought on other PC everything is working perfectly.

Properties: [image: General] [image: C++]

Comment: Have you compiled your project since changing the settings?

Comment: Yes I tried to compile it and it says that 'filesystem': a namespace or class of this name does not exist, 'filesystem': a namespace or class of this name does not exist. So it failed to compile.

Comment: It works fine for me. Perhaps your installation is corrupt?

Comment: It could be corrupted but the way to fix it is delete all the stuff and reinstall. So maybe I'm missing something. Also I already reinstalled C++ package for VS and update it.

Comment: Is the properties you've shown set for _All configurations_ and _All platforms_?

Comment: No, the one that I showed is for Active(Debug) for x64 platform.

Comment: Select _All configurations_ and _All platforms_ in the property page. Then set C++17 and apply.

Comment: And changing platrfom just solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. This will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Consider posting an answer instead as putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am simply adding the answer from the comments above since this helped me as well. Credit goes to Ted Lyngmo.

When changing properties, make sure either that the properties editing window is set to all configurations, or at least matches your current configuration (i. e., if you are on Debug x64, make sure those are the properties you are editing for). But if you want the property to be applied for all configurations, select All configurations on the properties editor.

[Snippet showing the properties editor below the configuration selector, in this case they don't match and it'll look like the property changes were ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsqaK.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, Ted won't get any credits in stackoverflow if your answer is marked as the solution.

Comment: Of course but he hasn't posted it as an answer. I am just trying to increase visibility of the answer and provide a visual indicator.

Comment: Yes, he seems to be somewhat inactive :/