# How To Use Latest Version Of Standard Library (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I need to use new standard library features, more specifically I need to use std::filesystem::directory_iterator. To use the standard library needs to be c++17 or higher. My compiler is using c++17 but it does not recognize the c++17 version of the standard library.

So my question is how to I use the latest standard library??? (I use visual studio and I use the MSVC compiler)

Comment: Which specific version of visual studio?

Comment: Have you actually set the mode to C++17 in Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio defaults to C++14 mode unless you specify otherwise.  Did you specify otherwise?

Comment: [This question asks something else, but gives good pictures of where to find the language dialect settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980146/cant-choose-c-language-standard-in-visual-studio-2019).